# Client Connect/Disconnect Issue - Liquidsoap

Tags: stream, streaming, audio-streaming, liquidsoap

Today, I tried to install Liquidsoap on Windows Server.

I installed a Windows Version of Liquidsoap and everything works (reading playlist, mp3s, ...) but I have a problem.

When someone tries to connect to my audio stream, it works but he gets disconnected in 1 second (so he has 2 seconds of music and nothing else).

Where can it come from?

In debug I get :

```
2012/05/08 16:19:23 Client .... connected
2012/05/08 16:19:23 Client .... disconnected
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post your liquidsoap script? Also you may want to ask the liquidsoap mailing list if this may be a bug.

Comment: What output method are you using?